# MSBuild - only build projects in my solution that have changed

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to set up CruiseControl.NET with a solution containing several projects. It is required that only projects in this solution are rebuild when there were changes. It's also required that the projects that will be build increase their version number.

I tried setting the configuration from **ReBuild** to **Build** but that did not help, still all assemblies are compiled.

Is there anyone that has made experience with CruiseControl.NET and that problem?

Comment: Rebuild and build only control how the solution is built, not which projects are built. Rebuild will do a clean before a standard build

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a cruisecontrol.net project for each vb/cs project, you can use the filteredSourceControlProvider to trigger the build only if a file is changed in the project path.

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered
Look at the inclusion filters.

Then setup your Msbuild task to build your project file directly.

However I suspect you have dependencies between your projects, hence them being in the same solution? If so you would probably want to build the solution each time?